# How to use HttpClient to POST to Web Api for registering a user

Tags: json, xamarin.android, async-await

I am doing a local testing base on Wifi:

1) My Development PC and Android phone connected to the same Wifi
2) Android phone is connected to Development PC
3) Web Api App and Xamarin android App are in this Development PC
4) Have Set a Static IPaddress for the PC as indicated in below code.

Problem:

I m using HttpClient in Android App to make a POST to the Asp.net Web Api in Local Testing Environment base on WiFi connection.

My objective is to register a user and I am expecting a HttpStatusCode like OK  and a user object from the Web Api as HttpResponseMessage

However,The Code below is not returning result.

So, I have these questions:

1) Is this Usr Obj can be used by JsonConvert 
  var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Usr);

2) can this DateTime.Today be used in the new User() class ?

3) are Async and await correctly used?

**Code:**

```
   [Activity(Label = "HttpClientPostApp", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
     public class MainActivity : Activity
     {
         Button HttpBtn;
         TextView txtView;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
           base.OnCreate(bundle)

          SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

           HttpBtn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.button1);
           txtView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tv1);

          HandleEvents();

        }


        private void HandleEvents()
        {
            HttpBtn.Click += HttpBtn_Click;
        }

     private async void HttpBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
           try
            {
             string str = await Register();

            }
          catch (Exception ex)
            {
               String str = ex.ToString();
            }

       }

      private async Task<string> Register()
      {
         try
         {
         var Usr = new User()
         {
             UserName = "User1",
             UserPassword = "1234567",
             UserEmailAddr = "r@m.com",
             UserMobileNo = "123456789",
             CreatedOn = DateTime.Today            

         };

       HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        var url = "http://192.168.1.3:9484/api/User";
        var uri = new Uri(url);


       //-- set up header
       client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
       client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Usr);
        var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);



        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
           var responceString = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);

           txtView.Text = responceString.ToString();
          return responceString.ToString();
        }
          return string.Empty;
       }      
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           String str = ex.ToString();
       }
    }
}
```

**Update : Web Api**

```
public HttpResponseMessage PostContact([FromBody] User contact)
{
    User ctc = repository.Add(contact);
    if (ctc != null)
     {
                return Request.CreateResponse<User>(HttpStatusCode.Created, ctc);
     }
     else
     {

    HttpError myCustomError = new HttpError("Unable to insert data into table.") { { "CustomErrorCode", 42 } };

     return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, myCustomError);

     }
}
```

**update latest:**

```
when system run at this point. it shows the Frame not in module.

 HttpClient client = new HttpClient();


-- the out put error i can get at the bottom is below

05-04 14:44:10.043 D/Mono    (20418): Probing 'monodroid_get_system_property'.
05-04 14:44:10.043 D/Mono    (20418): Found as 'monodroid_get_system_property'.
05-04 14:44:10.043 D/Mono    (20418): DllImport searching in: '__Internal' ('(null)').
05-04 14:44:10.043 D/Mono    (20418): Searching for 'monodroid_free'.
05-04 14:44:10.043 D/Mono    (20418): Probing 'monodroid_free'.
05-04 14:44:10.043 D/Mono    (20418): Found as 'monodroid_free'.
```

Your help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What is your question? What is your expected response? Please update your question with a question. Also, you need to `await`  the call to `ReadAsStringAsync` instead of blocking on `.Result`.

Comment: How to get the User and HttpStatusCode return from asp.net  web api? Thanks

Comment: (1) Yes, (2) Yes, (3) No -  Do not block with `.Result` `await` the call instead. It's not clear why you wouldn't deserailize the json string to a `User` but that's up to you. To find out why your getting nothing back set a break point in you controller's post method and follow the logic from there. Also, your checking the status code twice, `EnsureSuccessStatusCode` will throw an exception if the result is not success.

Comment: I have updated the code. I use DeserializeObj. I dont understand your point(3). I have set up the breakpoint in Web Api but there is no sign after I click the submit button on Android  app. Would appreciate if you can correct my code.

Comment: If there is a breakpoint on the first line of the method your calling in the web service and it is not getting hit in debug mode then your not calling that method. What is the status code of the response? Is an exception thrown? Finally, this line `response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result` is a blocking call change it to `await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()`.

Comment: See my latest update. When system run at this HttpClient client = new HttpClient(); it show a Frame not in module dialogbox.

Comment: I'm not following your comment can you clarify exactly what is going wrong?